# Javascript Regex to make command line parser for Text Adventure Game

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, parsing

I am trying to write a command line parser for a text adventure game. I have the commands written into an Array: Look, Talk, Get, etc...

How can I write a regex that will look for those commands at the beginning of the command line, ignore the words "at, with, on, etc.." and then pick up the rest of the words on the command line as a string. So for example, if the user typed in:
"Talk with the Lonely tree", I want the regex to find the "Talk" as a command, ignore "with the" and then turn "Lonely Tree" into a string. Any code suggestions to do that?

This is what I came up with and for some reason the page is blank when I put it into an HTML:

```
//Iterate through the array to see if a command was used
var myStringArray = ["Look","Talk","Take"];
var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
   //When it picks a particular word up it will save it.
   var str = "Talk with Lonely Tree";
  var textcmd = +str.split(' ')[0];

//replace the command word and unnecessary other words in the text
if (i == textcmd){

var objecttxt = str;
objecttxt = str.replace(textcmd, "")

var myUselessWords = ["on","with","at","to"];
var uselessLength = myUselessWords.length;
for (var t = 0; t < uselessLength; t++) {

var uselessCollection = [];
uselessCollection.push = t;

objecttxt = str.replace(t, "");

}
}
alert(objecttxt + " " + textcmd);
 }
```

Comment: Step 1: try something. Step 2: if it works, great! Otherwise, repeat step 1 until you run out of ideas, then ask for help and present what you have tried.

Comment: Sometimes we come to stackoverflow to get an idea of how to proceed. I am not asking to have a whole app written, just for assistance on the best way to do this. RegEx is not exactly the easiest thing to accomplish and throwing arrays into the mix only complicates it. So, I am just kind of looking into a kick start here.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with regex and just split by spaces into tokens, then compare each token against a map of commands and subjects

Comment: OK, so I tried doing it that way, sort of. Look at my revised code. Just shows up blank now.

Comment: I updated/fixed the code you posted here: http://jsfiddle.net/sj42wjtd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try a different approach:

```
var input = userinput; //however you get it
var commands = [/look/i, /take/i, /talk/i];
var gameObjects = []; //push objects here as they're created

var command = commands.filter(function(r) { return input.match(r); });
var object = gameObjects.filter(function(obj) {
    return input.match(new RegExp(obj.name, 'i');
});

if (command.length and object.length) {
    //do stuff, remember that String.prototype.match returns an array even
    //if there's only one match, so be sure to unbox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example, something like this should work:

```
 /(\blook|look|talk|get)\b.*\b(lonely\Wtree|something\Welse)\b/g
```

That would catch any of your commands with any "lonely tree"-object you specify. If you want to play around with RegExes, try http://regexr.com/

In your case, I guess your Regex could get pretty large if you have a lot of game commands and objects. It would be better for performance if you check for commands first and then for possible objects in a second step.

Comment: OK. I updated my original post and added a sample of how I would do that without RegEx. Would that work better? Also, what I am doing wrong with my code?

Comment: you should stay with RegEx because they are shorter and (usually) run much faster than custom String-handling code. You can use multiple Regexes to perform different checks on a String. E.g. you first validate if the input String doesn't consist of unwanted characters, then you do a check for the user command, then for the object of the sentence. Also, better use console.log() instead of alert() and check the javascript console. You're writing nothing to the DOM, that's why the browser stays blank.